# Let I, J ideals. Are they equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, computational-algebra, groebner-basis

Let

$$I= \langle 11x^5y+7xy^6+9,8xy^4+6xy+9 \rangle$$

$$J= \langle 7x^5y^2+17x^2y^5+29,13xy^4+62xy^3+19 \rangle$$

ideals. Examine whether those two ideals are equal.

By seeing their 3D plots I think they are not equal, but I dont know how to show it...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are these ideals in $\mathbb Z[x,y]$?

Comment: In \mathbb R[x,y]

Comment: The resultants of $I$ and $J$ with respect to $x$ are distinct, meaning that $I\cap\Bbb{R}[Y]\neq J\cap\Bbb{R}[Y]$, so these two ideals are not equal.

Comment: By the resultants with respect to x, you mean that I consider the polynomials in J for example as polynomials in the variable y and think of x as a constant?

Comment: You could perhaps try showing that the polynomials with integer coefficients in $I$ have constant terms constrained in a way in which the constant terms of polynomials with integer coefficients in $J$ are not?

Comment: Two ideals are equal if and only if they have the same (reduced) Gröbner basis (from wikipedia)
From wolfram alpha I found a Groebner base for each one and they are both different (but I dont know if they are reduced). Is that enough?

Comment: No, because the same ideal could have two different nonreduced Groebner bases. However if the Groebner bases aren't too big you can find quite easily the corresponding reduced Groebner bases: do you know the algorithm?

Comment: Yeah, I think I know how to do that.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Buchberger's algorithm to prove that those ideals are not equal. Pick any monomial order on $k[x,y]$ and construct the reduced Groebner basis for each of those ideals. Since reduced Groebner basis is unique for every ideal fixed, this approach will give a straightforward answer.

For, example, for grlex ($x \succ y$) ordering:
$$I = \langle 7y^5+11x^4-8y^3-6, \; 8xy^4+6xy+9, \; 88x^5-64xy^3-42xy^2-48x-63y \rangle,$$
while:
$$J = \langle 133x^4+323xy^3-377y^2-1798y, \;13xy^4+62xy^3+19, \;4901y^6+46748y^5+111476y^4+2527x^3+6137y^3 \rangle.$$
So $I \neq J$.

By the way, I think that this question should be tagged as a homework.